# Error when executing "Tor Browser"

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, tor-install

First:  I've never used Tor Browser or similar applications, so please forgive my noobness.

I'm pretty sure I've done everything correctly, but I still can't seem to connect.  I've downloaded the newest version of Tor.

I've disabled firewall and my free Avast anti-virus.  At least, I think I did.  I'm not too sure how to check on that.

When I open Tor Browser, the small window opens while "trying to connect."  However, I always get an error message "Could not connect to Tor control port."  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I'm running Win 7.

Answer (score 1):

That is a local problem which is probably related to your firewall. The control ports which need to be tunneled through the firewall are `9150` and `9151`.

1. at https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/11023 user "badon" says

   > I copied my portable Tor Browser Bundle to another drive, and it
   >   worked!

   you could give that a try, too
2. see if the problem occurs in Safe Mode with Networking (press F8 while starting to access)
3. try the TBB on a friend's computer to see if you have the same problem
4. follow the steps at https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/11776.
   (f.ex. by uninstalling your AV software)
5. check your firewall

   - see https://superuser.com/questions/611620/firewall-blocks-localhost-but-only-if-its-turned-on where the problem is in the `hosts` file.
   - https://superuser.com/questions/401900/how-to-block-localhost-connections-with-windows-7-2008r2-firewall says that the windows firewall should not be the problem if you are able to access tor.sx.
   - have a look at [official documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/understanding-firewall-settings#1TC=windows-7).
6. There are directions on changing your ports from 9150/9151 to others at https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13150
7. download [TAILS](https://tails.boum.org/) to a USB stick and boot from it to use Tor.

Comment: I apologize, but have no idea what the above solutions are.  I've turned my firewall off, so I dunno how much answers 1 and 2 helps.  Am I missing another way to disable windows 7 firewall?  I've done number 3...

Comment: @adcindy: have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/26564/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-blocked-on-a-windows-machine and https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/configure-firewalls-so-firefox-can-access-internet

Comment: Is there a site which has some basic information on this stuff?  I literally don't know half the things that are talked about here.  I've completely disabled my windows firewall and deleted my antivirus, so I don't know what the holdup is.  I have no idea how to do that port stuff or find logs or any of that.  I'm a noob without this deep computer knowledge who wants to simply browse online without the government or other no-gooders gathering up my information.

Comment: @adcindy: there are some updates. Say back if they helped.

Comment: @adcindy Just as a double check, you may want to open the Windows Task Manager -> Processes tab. I have noticed that tor.exe sometimes is running when you don't expect it to be. If it is running, highlight tor.exe with the mouse and then click the "End Process" button before attempting to restart the TOR browser.