# Installed Tor, tried to run got message "could not connect to Tor control port"

Tags: help

New to Tor. I've had it before on an old laptop with no issues but I recently installed it on my desktop and haven't been able to run it. I've tried reinstalling and disabling all firewalls and antivirus programs but I still get the same message which is: "Could not connect to Tor control port". When I try to copy the Tor log to the clipboard through the Tor program it says there's nothing to copy even after I try connecting and get the error message.

I've looked everywhere online and I haven't seen any solutions that have worked. I don't know how to see if the port Tor uses is free or not. I've tried using the command prompt command "netstat -an |find /i [portnumber]" but it says my find is improper format despite it being correct from everything I've read about it.

Anyways, any help resolving the "Could not connect to Tor control port" error message would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Anti-virus, firewalls and other "security" software is often the cause.

Comment: I've disabled all firewalls and security software in additon to adding exemptions for everything in the Tor folder and I still get the "could not connect to control port" every single time. I've even figured out how to check which ports are being used and the default Tor control port 9151 is not in use. I have zero clue how to resolve this and it's very frustrating.

Comment: My guess would be that something is stopping Tor from launching in the first place, since there are no logs being produced and it's not binding to the control port. See [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8869/error-when-executing-tor-browser) which is a similar problem.

Comment: I have no idea what half of those instructions mean or what they want me to do. I doubt it's the firewall as I have added exemptions to the Tor Browser's location in Avast and I have the same probelm in Safe Mode with networking. I can ping 127.0.0.1 but I have no idea what the means at all. The steps at 11776 are very unclear. I tried starting a log through command prompt, the Tor console log came up but nothing was logged.

My only other option would be to try on a different computer but I would really like to use this one hence the entire point of this post. I'll try uninstalling Avast!

Comment: Son of a....Avast was the problem. Even though I added an exception to Tor Browser it still blocked the ports for some reason. That's silly. My VPN not working must be caused by the same issue. Is there an anti-virus that you can recommend that doesn't arbitrarily block TOR and VPNs?

Comment: Use Microsoft's builtin software, it's well known to play the nicest with other software. It doesn't have all the bells and whistles but it does a reasonable job and isn't horrible insecure (see: Tavis Ormandy's work on antivirus as a way to exploit a computer)

Comment: Strangley, I just reinstalled Avast! and Tor seems to be working now. I guess it's something I'll never understand. 

Thanks for being so patient and helpful and sorry for being impatient and stubborn. Is there any way to leave a review or increase your profile rating?